# multiple chart when mouse hover

Tags: angular, chart.js

I use chart.js library in my Angular application.
I have a problem the same as here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c61Fs0itRdM

```
            this.canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
            this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');                
            let myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
              type: 'pie',
              data: {
                  labels: Array.from(data.keys()),
                  datasets: [{
                      label: 'example chart',
                      data: Array.from(data.values()),
                      backgroundColor: [
                          'rgba(255, 99, 11, 1)',
                          'rgba(54, 162, 34, 1)'
                      ],
                      borderWidth: 1
                  }]
              },
              options: {
                responsive: false,
                display:true
              }
            });
```

But based on solution provided in above video I can't find out how to clear canvas context in my application.
Help please!

Comment: We won't look at a video to know what your problem is. That should be clearly stated in your question.

Comment: @JBNizet the problem is not easy to describe, someone has recorded the video for clarification. Although I'll try to describe it myself.

Comment: Instead of clearing the canvas. Just update the data and label(if you want). To do this do myChart.data.datasets[0].data = [] to update data and myChart.data.labels = [] for new label.

Comment: Setting datasets to new empty array didn't work. The solution is:
                if (this.myChart) this.myChart.destroy(); //destroy previous chart instance